# Adding a datarow from an existing table to a new table

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, asp.net-3.5, datarow

Hi i want to add a datarow that im getting back from a data table to a new datatable

this is the code im using:

```
foreach (DataRow dr1 in dt.Rows)
{
  string AptType = dr1["AppointmentType"].ToString();
  if (AptType == "FreeTime")
  {
    dt2.ImportRow(dr1);
  }
}
RadGrid2.DataSource = dt2;
reader.Close();
conn.Close();
```

the problem is that when i then go to run the page with the table on it im getting a datakey error and that one of the columns isnt being recognised

thanks in advance

Comment: What the the exception message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the two data tables have the same schema?  Those errors might be thrown if they do not match columns, datatypes, or keys.

Comment: they should have the same schema i havent done this before do i need to set the columns first because i thought that the clone function did that.

Comment: Not if datatable 2 is a clone of datatable 1, or vice versa.  Clone() copies all columns and constraints.  Could you post a simplified schema of your tables?

Comment: #TempEngineerGroupMain 
  (
   AppointmentType VARCHAR(50),
   BookedDate DateTime, 
   BookedFromTime DateTime, 
   BookedToTime DateTime, 
   TotalDays INT,  
   JobMins INT
  )

thats the temp table that my stored proc is bring back

Comment: Good, but not helpful.  Can you post the exact error messages?

Comment: thanks for your help on this i have fixed it it was a case of schema's being wrong between the tables and me suffering sleep deprevation not noticing it

Answer (score 0):

You should use Typed TableDataAdapters, I would make your life so much easier...

This is very easy to do and to understand.

Follow this tutorial [Strongly Typed TableDataAdapters and DataTables](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/15/435498.aspx)

Once you grasp the concept, you should do something like this:

```
MyTypedTableAdapter tableAdapter = new MyTypedTableAdapter();
    MyTypedDataTable dt = tableAdapter.GetData();
    foreach (MyTypedDataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        string AptType = row.AppointmentType;
        if (AptType == "FreeTime")
        {
            dt2.ImportRow(row);
        }
    }
    RadGrid2.DataSource = dt2;
```